# Apt-get holds back kernel images (generic, server and extra)

Tags: apt, updates, aptitude

Today, apt-get told me several packages have been held back. Typing `apt-get dist-upgrade -su` gave me this:

```
 apt-get dist-upgrade -su
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed
  linux-image-3.13.0-44-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-44-generic
The following packages will be upgraded:
  linux-image-generic linux-image-server
2 to upgrade, 2 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
Inst linux-image-3.13.0-44-generic (3.13.0-44.73 Ubuntu:14.04/trusty-updates [amd64])
Inst linux-image-extra-3.13.0-44-generic (3.13.0-44.73 Ubuntu:14.04/trusty-updates [amd64])
Inst linux-image-server [3.13.0.43.50] (3.13.0.44.51 Ubuntu:14.04/trusty-updates [amd64]) []
Inst linux-image-generic [3.13.0.43.50] (3.13.0.44.51 Ubuntu:14.04/trusty-updates [amd64])
Conf linux-image-3.13.0-44-generic (3.13.0-44.73 Ubuntu:14.04/trusty-updates [amd64])
Conf linux-image-extra-3.13.0-44-generic (3.13.0-44.73 Ubuntu:14.04/trusty-updates [amd64])
Conf linux-image-generic (3.13.0.44.51 Ubuntu:14.04/trusty-updates [amd64])
Conf linux-image-server (3.13.0.44.51 Ubuntu:14.04/trusty-updates [amd64])
```

I am unsure on the course of action. If the server does not reboot, or if grub doesn't automatically boot the right kernel, I will be locked out of the server, at 800 km, doomed to spend a lot of money on a human intervention. I have no physical access to the server.

Is it expected from a 14.04 server to want to install all this? Which kernel will boot automatically? Server? Extra? Generic?

My current kernel is `3.13.0-43-generic #72-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 8 19:35:06 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`.

Also, I must confess that I may have screwed up with the apt-get source list file when installing the server from the Perfect server guide of sourceforge (14.04, apache). 
When "resetting" my dedicated webserver, the hosting company performs an automatic installation of the linux distribution I choose. I selected 14.04 generic (which means, in theory, they didn't modify it too much). But it came with a sources.list file containing repositories hosted by the company. I didn't know what to do, so I just added those recommended from the `sourceforge` guide, just to be sure. Aptitude did complain a little bit (telling me it deactivated some stuff), but then then it carried on happily, and so did I with the setup of my server.

Is this issue coming back to haunt me?

Below is my current sources.list file.

```
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://ubuntu.mirrors.ovh.net/ftp.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
deb-src http://ubuntu.mirrors.ovh.net/ftp.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://ubuntu.mirrors.ovh.net/ftp.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
deb-src http://ubuntu.mirrors.ovh.net/ftp.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://ubuntu.mirrors.ovh.net/ftp.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb-src http://ubuntu.mirrors.ovh.net/ftp.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb http://ubuntu.mirrors.ovh.net/ftp.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
deb-src http://ubuntu.mirrors.ovh.net/ftp.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://ubuntu.mirrors.ovh.net/ftp.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb-src http://ubuntu.mirrors.ovh.net/ftp.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb http://ubuntu.mirrors.ovh.net/ftp.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
deb-src http://ubuntu.mirrors.ovh.net/ftp.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://ubuntu.mirrors.ovh.net/ftp.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://ubuntu.mirrors.ovh.net/ftp.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernels are typically held back automatically.  This is because some administrators don't want to update to kernels because things might break and explode (metaphorically).

Your course of action should be as such:

1. Update (`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` or similar) to the latest kernel **if you want the fixes included in it** and are willing to remove the latest kernel if it fails.  Make a note of the version of your kernel you have now first (`uname -a`), and what the highest version number that is being installed is.  You may need this info later.
2. Boot to the newly installed kernel.  If all boots fine and works, then go to 3(a).  Otherwise, go to 3(b).
3. Steps to Take:
   (a) If all works fine, you can try and use an autoremove to get the old kernels gone.  You can erase the old kernel to conserve space, or keep the kernel around as a backup.  `sudo apt-get autoremove` is a good start point.  If nothing is removed then you need to go hunting to remove the older kernels.
   (b) If all does *not* work fine, then when booting at grub, choose "Other options" or similar, and choose the older kernel number that you kept and referenced.  Choose the kernel from that list.  Then remove the newly installed kernel versions (this is why I said to take down the package versions and names)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I get the latest kernel with `uname -a`, it is the one running, right? How do I see the autoremove list? Is there a guide explaining how to do 3a or 3b?

Comment: @Adeline if you're not sure you can always find other questions here, however the point still stands that if you know how to remove software then you just do this for 3b: `sudo apt-get remove linux-image-3.13.0-44-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-44-generic` and the newest kernel that didn't work goes away.  Hence why I said record the information down.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It answers the question, I guess. But I can't go with the solution because using apt-get remove requires to be able to boot the server… and to be able to connect to it with ssh.

Comment: @Adeline well, if the server is a remote server then you'll need to use a VNC client or serial connection (most VPSes have this virtual client).  You don't *have* to upgrade the kernel though.  As well, you'd need to reboot to finish installing the new kernel anyways.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The two tools I have are : SSH (if server can boot and bring ssh up) and SSH in rescue mode (server boots elsewhere, harddrive is not mounted, this mode never fails). How can I finish installing new kernels without rebooting? Sometimes my server tells me "the system needs to reboot" when logging in.

Comment: @Adeline you can't finish new kernel setup without a reboot - you can't load the new kernel except at boot time, hence it saying it needs a reboot to finish 'installing' the kernel so it can be used.  Kernel updates always require a reboot but for a production environment you can ignore most kernel updates and apply them during regular maintenance periods.